# find y coordinate of a point P when given x

Tags: matlab, coordinates

I find the `x` coordinate of the point by this code:

```
for j = 1:length(masks)
    [b_x,b_y] = find(bwperim(masks{1,j}.A)== 1);
    P(j)=min(b_x);
end
```

I want the `y` coordinate of each point of `P(j)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) function can also give you the index of the minimal value, that can be used to solve your problem:

```
for j = 1:length(masks)
  [b_x,b_y] = find(bwperim(masks{1,j}.A)== 1);
  [P_x(j),I]=min(b_x);
  P_y(j) = b_y(I);
end
```

Comment: for the same problem if i have this code  

        for j = 1:length(masks)
        stat=regionprops(masks{1,j}.A,'BoundingBox');
        x=stat.BoundingBox(1);
       end

How can I find the y?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what the problem is, but I guess what you need is `y = stat.BoundingBox(1);`.

Comment: stat.BoundingBox(1); give the x position of the corner top-left of the bounding box of an object i want to have the y coordinate related to this x

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking, I meant to write `y = stat.BoundingBox(2);`